# Issue caused by subtle misuse of the add link button

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, editor

In the add link dialog, entering the code

```
http://example.com/ "optional title"
```

...gives the link [enter link description here](http://example.com/), as expected, to example.com.

However, using a trailing dot, like

```
http://example.com/ "optional title".
```

...gives a link to `http://example.com/%20%22optional%20title%22.`, clearly not what is intended. ([enter link description here](http://example.com/%20%22optional%20title%22.)).

Could some warning be shown in this situation?

Also, could the text `optional title` be changed to `optional hover text`?

[image]

Comment: For who voted "The problem described here can no longer be reproduced": I can surely reproduce it. (I don't think that warning about the excessive trailing dot is important enough to fix, but others might feel different.)